# How do I burn a DVD in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, burning, iso-image

I want to burn two DVDs:

- On the first one I want to burn a .iso file to the DVD. It's a Windows 7 .iso file.
- On the second one I want to burn two files.

How do I burn these two different DVDs? Should I use a third party tool or I can handle this using tools built-in to Windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 has support for burning ISOs built in. Just double-click on the ISO or right-click and choose "Open with" -> "Windows Disk Image Burner" if some other program is set to open ISOs by default. The image burning wizard will open. Select the drive to burn to, insert a disk, then click "burn".

[image: windows image burner]

---

To burn regular files to a disk, insert a disk, then go to the folder where your files are stored. Click "Burn" in the toolbar at the top of the window. Choose "with a CD/DVD player", then click "next". You can then drag-and-drop additional files into the window which opens, then click "burn to disc" once you're done copying over the files.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Damn that is a better faster answer than I had.  Good work!

Comment: Small correction, Right click on ISO and choose "Open With" then select "Windows Disc Image Burner Burner".

Comment: True, if something else is set to the default handler for ISOs. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

I use [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/) for all of my burning needs.  Don't let the name fool you, it works just fine on Windows 7.

However you can also use [built in tools](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2008/11/03/that-took-long-enough-windows-7-can-burn-iso-files/) to burn a disc.

Your second DVD of just files should could also be done just in Windows Explorer.  Drag the files you want to your DVD burner, insert blank DVD and burn it. [Better instructions here.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Burn-a-CD-or-DVD)

Answer (score 0):

You can burn many different types of CDs and DVDs in Windows Media Center. This lets you decide what type of DVD or CD you want to create, based on how and what you want to use to play the content after it is burned to a disc.

This guy also explains in some easy steps:
http://www.zdnet.com/blog/hardware/how-to-burn-your-windows-7-iso-to-dvd-disc/3317